# Executing RE Using regex.h in C. Match & Count any numbers in String

Tags: c, regex, linux

I am trying to extract numbers from a file. I have limitation that I need to use only `open()`, `read()` and `close()`.

I have read my data successfully and saved in a buffer. No I need to match it to RE.
I am using RE = ^[0-9]*

This is my code for this

```
char buffer[1024] = { NULL };
int count = 0;
int fRead;

fRead = open("file.in", O_RDONLY);
read(fRead, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
printf("\nFile Opened %s, %lu", buffer, sizeof(buffer));

/* Compile regular expression */
regex_t re;
int reti = regcomp(&re, "^[1-9]*", 0);
if (reti) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n");
    exit(1);
}

/* Execute regular expression */
reti = regexec(&re, buffer, 0, NULL, 0);
if (!reti) {
    printf("\nMatch: %d", reti);
} else if (reti == REG_NOMATCH) {
    puts("No match");
} else {
    char msgbuf[100];
    regerror(reti, &re, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
    fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
    exit(1);
}
close(fRead);
```

Now the problem is I want to count and display the digits I found in my file.
For example my file may have text `some thing 2 to 3 makes 5`, in such case my out put must be
OUTPUT:
`2,3,5
count = 3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [man page for regexec](http://linux.die.net/man/3/regexec).  The return value of regexec is, as you are using it, 0 for success or a positive error code.  However, the other parameters to regexec are how you get more information about matches.

For convenience, here's the definition of regexec:

```
int regexec(const regex_t *preg, const char *string, size_t nmatch,
            regmatch_t pmatch[], int eflags);
```

The pmatch parameter is where the function puts its matches if it finds them, and the nmatch parameter tells the function how many elements the pmatch parameter has so it doesn't overflow.  This works similarly to other languages "match" function where the first index of pmatch will have the full regex match while the following indexes will have subgroup matches.  That means that you'll need to use a subgroup match to get the number out of the string, and then you'll need to loop over the string to find subsequent subgroup matches.

First, instantiate a regmatch_t stack variable to hold the results.  This just needs to be size 2 so you can store the full match in the 0 index and the subgroup match in the 1 index.  You also need to change you regex so it matches the whole string until it gets to a number.  We will pass it through to the regexec function along with its size for nmatch.

Each time a match is found you will need to move the start of the string forward so that the next time you call regexec on it you will get *the next number* and not the same one.

First update the regex string.

```
/* if we use .* in the regex it will be greedy and match the last number, not the first.
   We need to use a + instead of a * for the number so we know there is at least 1. */
int reti = regcomp(&re, "[^0-9]*([0-9]+)", REG_EXTENDED);
```

Then loop to find all the matches.

```
/* regmatch_t is defined in regex.h */
regmatch_t matches[2];
int start;
int end;  

while (1) {
  reti = regexec(&re, buffer, 2, matches, 0);

  /* rm_so is the start index of the match */
  start = matches[1].rm_so;
  /* rm_eo is the end index of the match */
  end = matches[1].rm_eo;
  /* break if we didn't find a match */
  if (reti) break;

  /* print the substring that contains the match */
  printf("%.*s, ", (end - start), (buffer + start));
  /* increment the count of matches */
  count = count + 1;

  /* This is really important!
     Move the start of the string forward so we don't keep matching the same number! */
  buffer = buffer + end;
} 

/* print the count */
printf("count = %d", count);
```

Comment: I've tried this, but still my output count is 0; Why is it so?
I've copied and pasted this code in my code.
and also change RE, Now RE is [1-9]

Comment: Actually its not entering While Loop due to this
`matches[pmatch_index].rm_so != -1` condition

Comment: Hmmm, testing it I am also not getting into the loop.  It looks like regexec is marking the full match as 0,0 (if you look at matches[0] you will probably see rm_so and rm_eo set to 0).  I will try to figure out if I did something wrong here.

Comment: Please try to figure it out, I am also trying.
I have only 1 hour left in submitting this code. I seriously need help :|

Comment: Ah, I see what I did.  pmatch is actually used for storing subexpression matches.  I will fix it and post an update.

Comment: Okay, updated and should work now.  Let me know if you have other problems.